# Iterating table fields to create individual Shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder, attribute-table, iterator

I am trying to create individual shapefiles from a single table that contains the following:

- Weather Station Names
- Station XY Cordinates
- 31 individual field columns of daily data for each weather station

I am trying to use the iterate field values from another spreadsheet that contains only a single column the date of the weather data that I want to create each individual shapefile.  The dates in that spreadsheet match the column field heading in the spreadsheet that contains the daily data.

I am getting an error in the Make XY Event Layer when I try to set the "Z Field" to "Value" for the iteration process.  I have attached an image of my model below.

[image: model]

Any advice on how to get this thing to run?

Comment: Don't quite understand how your Z-value is coming from the table you said only contains dates, can you illustrate further?  Also what ver of ArcGIS?

Comment: Leave the Z value blank according to your description.

Comment: I left the Z field blank and the model created the individual shape files that I wanted but each shape file still contains all of the attributes of the original table.  I want each shape file to only have the data for each individual day.  For example, for the July 1st 2011 shape file , i just want the attribute table to have the XY coordinates and only the July 1st data.  If all the attribute table is still there, is there a way to iterate to delete all the other attributes other than the data for the day of the individual shape file?

Comment: I think you should include some more screenshots like a few rows from your two input tables, the parameter settings on the dialog for the Make XY Event Layer tool (since that is the one not colouring up to show that it is ready to run), and especially the text of the error that you said you are seeing.  With those it may be possible for one of us to try and reproduce what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a shapefile for each station with these 31 fields (daily weather readings) and your rows contain weather station records, you are making a logical mistake. Your Make XY Event tool expects two fields to yield locations but Iterate Field will return only one (field, field value). So, the tool becomes blank expecting to be introduced **correct input** parameters.

Instead of iterating fields, you should use [Iterate Row Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000010000000). However you should Join your data at the outset or later. Assuming July_ETo_gdb is your station table, first Join this to your other dbf and place row iterator to this station table. Then use XY Event tool which will carry over the row values for then shapefile output.

Lastly Feature Class to Shapefile may not be the right choice here, you should be using Copy Features tool instead, I think.

Comment: I not trying to create an individual shapefile for each station.  I want a single shapfefile for each day.  There are a total of approximately 40 weather stations and so each station should have a value for that single day.  The "2011_July_Dates.dbf" table contains only a single column of the dates for July 2011.  The 31 field column headings in the "July_ETo_gdb.dbf" have the each date to match the dates table.  I just want a single shapefile for each day that has the daily value for each weather station.